# Passing a method of a big object to imap: 1000-fold speed-up by wrapping the method

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Assume `yo = Yo()` is a big object with a method `double`, which returns its parameter multiplied by `2`.

If I pass `yo.double` to `imap` of `multiprocessing`, then it is incredibly slow, because every function call creates a copy of `yo` I think.

Ie, this is very slow:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


class Yo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = np.random.random((10000000, 10))

    def double(self, x):
        return 2 * x

yo = Yo()    

with Pool(4) as p:
    for _ in tqdm(p.imap(yo.double, np.arange(1000))):
        pass
```

Output:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1it [00:06,  6.54s/it]
2it [00:11,  6.17s/it]
3it [00:16,  5.60s/it]
4it [00:20,  5.13s/it]
```

...

BUT, if I wrap `yo.double` with a function `double_wrap` and pass it to `imap`, then it is essentially instantaneous.

```
def double_wrap(x):
    return yo.double(x)

with Pool(4) as p:
    for _ in tqdm(p.imap(double_wrap, np.arange(1000))):
        pass
```

Output:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1000it [00:00, 14919.34it/s]
```

How and why does wrapping the function change the behavior?

I use Python 3.6.6.

Comment: Something unclear with my answer?

Comment: @Darkonaut I just don't understand why making the function module level prevents copying of the object. After all, the function needs to have a pointer to the ```yo``` object itself – which should require all processes to copy ```yo``` as they cannot share memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the copying. `yo.double` is a 'bound method', bound to your big object. When you pass it into the pool-method, it will pickle the whole instance with it, send it to the child processes and unpickle it there. This happens for every chunk of the iterable a child process works on. The default value for `chunksize` in `pool.imap` is 1, so you are hitting this communication overhead for every processed item in the iterable.

Contrary when you pass `double_wrap`, you are just passing a module-level function. Only it's name will actually get pickled and the child processes will import the function from `__main__`. Since you're obviously on an OS which supports forking, your `double_wrap` function will have access to the forked `yo` instance of `Yo`. Your big object won't be serialized (pickled) in this case, hence the communication overhead is tiny compared to the other approach.

---

> @Darkonaut I just don't understand why making the function module level prevents copying of the object. After all, the function needs to have a pointer to the yo object itself – which should require all processes to copy yo as they cannot share memory.

The function running in the child process will automatically find a reference to a global `yo`, because your operating system (OS) is using fork to create a child process. Forking leads to a clone of your whole parent process and as long neither the parent nor the child alter a specific object, both will see the same object in the same memory place.

Only if parent or child change something on the object, the object get's copied in the child process. That's called "copy-on-write" and happens at OS level without you taking notice of it in Python. Your code wouldn't work on Windows, which uses 'spawn' as start method for new processes.

Now I'm simplifying a bit above where I write "the object gets copied", since the unit the OS operates on is a "page" (most commonly this will be of size 4KB). This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135787/9059420) would be a good follow up read for broading your understanding.