# Dask: Update published dataset periodically and pull data from other clients

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I would like to append data on a `published dask dataset` from a queue (like redis). Then other python programs would be able to fetch the latest data (e.g. once per second/minute) and do some futher opertions.

1. Would that be possible?
2. Which append interface should be used? Should I load it into a `pd.DataFrame` first or better use some text importer?
3. What are the assumed append speeds? Is it possible to append lets say 1k/10k rows in a second?
4. Are there other good suggestions to exchange huge and rapidly updating datasets within a dask cluster?

Thanks for any tips and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here.

- You might take a look at the streamz project
- You might take a look at Dask's [coordination primitives](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives)

> What are the assumed append speeds? Is it possible to append lets say 1k/10k rows in a second?

Dask is just tracking remote data.  The speed of your application has a lot more to do with how you choose to represent that data (like python lists vs pandas dataframes) than with Dask.  Dask can handle thousands of tasks a second.  Each of those tasks could have a single row, or millions of rows.  It's up to how you build it.