# What is the right way to share a read only configuration to multiple processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a python application which is going to create a process for each element of the given inputs colleftion.  The inputs is a collection of about 8 elements. And the application reads a topic to get 8 elements periodically.

For each element of the input, I create a new process and pass in the input to a function.

The function is CPU bound in nature, it performs numerical operations.

My application has a Configuration object which is a dictionary. I load the data in the configuration at the time of loading the main process and then create a pool with 8 worker subpools.

What is the right mechanism to pass the configuration object in each of the process? I don't want to increase the memory footprint of the process.

As an example:

```
# cpu intensive operation
def cpu_bound(input):
    ...  # complex cpu bound op
    # I want to use config here

    return output


def get_config():
    # create configuration object
    config = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "loggers": {
            "": {
                "level": "INFO"
            }, 
            "another.module": {
                "level": "DEBUG"
            }
        }
    }


def pool_handler(inputs):
    p = Pool(8)  # 8 core machine
    results = p.map(cpu_bound, inputs)
    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":

    config = get_config()
    # get inputs from a topic
    inputs = get_inputs()
    results = pool_handler(inputs)
```

**Question**
What is the recommended approach to use the configuration within each process? The configuration is read-only in nature as I only need to load it once at boot up of the application. There are multiple ways but what is the recommended approach for this scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by read-only? Is there any particular problem with what you have now?

Comment: I should have mentioned. Thanks. Read-only as in, I only need to create it once for my application before I query the topic. My question is what is the best practice to share data?

Comment: I don’t know, just pass it as an argument?

Comment: If you don't know then let others answer

Comment: @InfoLearner: If `cpu_bound` needs additional information pass it to the function. In case you would run out of memory, thats not because of that little configuration object.

Comment: Thanks. I want to set up a pattern for the team. The configuration object will grow with api objects and other entities. I have noticed that the memory footprint increases when I pass it as an argument to the method. Is there a way to eliminate it so that I dont copy the object around? Should I use Value, Array, Queue etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135787/594589

Comment: Thanks for repening it. It was the right and smart decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to share static information within `multiprocessing.Pool` consist in using the `initializer` function to set it via its `initargs`.

The two above variables are in fact passed to the `Pool` workers as `Process` constructor parameters thus following the recommendations of the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L319).

> Explicitly pass resources to child processes
>
> On Unix using the fork start method, a child process can make use of a shared resource created in a parent process using a global resource. However, it is better to pass the object as an argument to the constructor for the child process.

```
variable = None


def initializer(*initargs):
    """The initializer function is executed on each worker process
    once they start.

    """
    global variable

    variable = initargs


def function(*args):
    """The function is executed on each parameter of `map`."""
    print(variable)


with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=initializer, initargs=[1, 2, 3]) as pool:
    pool.map(function, (1, 2, 3))
```