# Formatting a large list of images is taking longer using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, list, multiprocessing

I am currently processing 15k images but that number could grow to more at some point. I wrote a function that makes several changes to the images such as convert them to black and white, crop, resize and then flattening them. At a later time I will save the formatted images to a csv file for later use with tensorflow. I am using the multiprocessing module to utilize more cores on my CPU. It seems that it takes longer using multiprocessing then it does using a for loop to edit a single image at a time. I also wrote a simple version of the same program that squares a series of numbers. Using multiprocessing for that is actually faster.

Would I be better off splinting the data into batches? I wrote a generator to give me different batches but I couldn't get multiprocessing to work with it.

Compares the times of formatting images with multiprocessing verses sequential function calls

```
            # comparing time for image formating using
            # sequential and multiprocessing
            # vonderasche
            # 2/3/2019

            import multiprocessing as mp
            import time
            import numpy as np
            import cv2
            import os
            import sys

            def my_format_images(image):
                ''' converts to BW, crops, resizes and then flattens the image'''

                image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                height, width = image.shape

                if (height < width):
                    x_start = int((width - height) / 2)
                    x_end = height + x_start
                    image = image[0:height, x_start:x_end]

                elif (width < height):
                    y_start = int((height - width) / 2)
                    y_end = width + y_start
                    image = image[y_start:y_end, 0:width]

                image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 100))

                image = image.flatten()

                return image

            def load_images(path):
                '''loads images from a provided path'''

                print('loading images')
                image_list = []
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                    for file in files:
                        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, file))
                            image_list.append(img)
                    return image_list

            def main():

                path = 'images'
                images = load_images(path)

                print('total images loaded: ' + str(len(images)))

                # multiprocessing function call
                start_mp_timer = time.time()
                pool = mp.Pool(4)
                result = pool.map(my_format_images, images)
                end_mp_timer = time.time() - start_mp_timer

                # sequential function call
                sum_of_single_thread = []
                start_timer = time.time()
                for i in images:
                    num = my_format_images(i)
                    sum_of_single_thread.append(num)
                end_timer = time.time() - start_timer

                print('multiprocessing time: ' + ' {: 05.5f}'.format(end_mp_timer) + ' sequential time: ' +' {: 05.5f}'.format(end_timer))

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                main()
            main()
```

Simple version that squares a series of numbers to see that multiprocessing works.

```
    # multiprocessing - test using numbers
    # vonderasche
    # 2/3/2019

    import multiprocessing as mp
    import time
    import os

    def square(x):
      ''' prints the current process id and returns the square'''
      print(os.getpid())
      return x**x

    def main():

      data = [4784, 2454, 34545, 54545,
                                  34545, 24545, 1454, 454542, 52221, 11242, 88478, 447511]

      # multiprocessing function call
      pool = mp.Pool(4)
      start_mp_timer = time.time()
      result = pool.map(square, data)
      end_mp_timer = time.time() - start_mp_timer


      #  sequential function call
      sum_of_single_thread = []

      start_timer = time.time()
      for i in data:
          num = square(i)
          sum_of_single_thread.append(num)
      end_timer = time.time() - start_timer

      print('multiprocessing time: ' + '{:05.5f}'.format(end_mp_timer))
      print('sequential time: ' + '{:05.5f}'.format(end_timer))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Comment: Maybe consider converting to greyscale **on load** rather than reading in RGB, creating 3x the memory pressure and then converting to greyscale later?

Comment: You are also serially loading all the images at the start. You'd probably be better off  generating a glob/list of just the filenames (without loading them) and doing the loading and resizing in parallel under multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into an issue where multi-processing will copy the memory of the parent process when creating child processes. See [Python multiprocessing memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749897/python-multiprocessing-memory-usage) .

To confirm, I would suggest two programs: both do some math stuff in a pool, but one loads a bunch of stuff into memory before creating the pool. I would expect the one that loaded a bunch of stuff into memory first to have a slower multiprocessing time, even though the stuff isn't used by the pool.

If this is the case, my solution would be to do the loading inside the processes.